# add text to -webkit-slider-runnable-track

Tags: css, text, slider

I want to add text on top of a slider-runnable-track in a slider created with . If I could reference the runnable-track element in JavaScript, which doesn't seem possible, I could do it

Comment: The sliders at http://vispo.com/aleph3/an.html illustrate where I want to add text to the sliders.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to say "created with input type=range"

Comment: I realize one could add a background image, but the text I want to add is dynamic, it includes the value of the slider.